# FluentNHibernate acts differently on different machines

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have run into an issues with FluentNHibernate that i hope someone can help me with.

I have a many-to-many relationship between two classes named CampaignAreas and CampaignProducts. Sadly Fluent doesn't map the relation-table to the same table name on my machine as it does on my colleagues. It is named CampaignProductsToCampaignAreas and CampaignAreasToCampaignProducts respectivly.

We have the exact same version of the code, the same dll'es for NH, fluent etc. and we have been rebuilding and resetting IIS several times, so its not any of that basic stuff.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using auto mapping, or are you mapping it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of Fluent NHibernate you're using, there were some race-conditions with naming tables in a bi-directional many-to-many relationship; FNH used to pick whichever side of the relationship it found first, and for whatever reason .Net would give them in a different order (we just call `Assembly.GetTypes()`).

Anyway, I digress. Try upgrading to the latest version of FNH, and I'd also suggest you follow [Maggie's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385518/fluentnhibernate-acts-differently-on-different-machines/2387036#2387036) and use a convention to control table naming.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Christian. I'm using FHN v.1.2 and a many-to-many convention similar to what you suggest but FHN still generates different table names on my machine and my colleague's machine. Is there anything else I can do besides setting the table name explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I use this convention to name a many-to-many table with AutoMapping

```
  public class CustomManyToManyTableNameConvention : ManyToManyTableNameConvention
  {
    protected override string GetBiDirectionalTableName(IManyToManyCollectionInspector collection, IManyToManyCollectionInspector otherSide)
    {
      return String.Format("{1}{0}", collection.EntityType.Name, otherSide.EntityType.Name);
    }

    protected override string GetUniDirectionalTableName(IManyToManyCollectionInspector collection)
    {
      return String.Format("{1}{0}", collection.EntityType.Name, collection.ChildType.Name);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Fluent, but you should be able to specify the table name of the many-to-many relation. This would be cleaner anyway.

Comment: Problem is i am trying to avoid writing the map myself. The automapping does work, so it shouldent be a problem besides that it changes the name on one machine.